# Anaconda (win7 x64) python 2.7 import *.so (C++)?

Tags: c++, python, python-2.x

Помогите разобраться - может в Win python нельзя импортировать сишные библиотеки so?

Поставил Anaconda (64 bit) + python 2.7 на Windows 7 (x64),
запускаю проект, успешно протестированный на Linux. При запуске python скрипта не видит файлик gcode.so (сишная библиотека), ругается на `import gcode`.

Не нашел, как в анаконде задаются переменные среды `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` для того, чтобы узнать в какую папку анаконды класть эту библиотеку. Положил в anaconda\lib - не видит.

Может для виндовой анаконды нужна не SO, а DLL? Или я чего-то недонастроил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*.so` - свой формат и очень сомневаюсь, что можно просто взять и загрузить его в винде (хотя если постараться его правильно написать - можно), так что нужна DLL

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека должна быть DLL для винды или импорт через Cython